# Django display a value from a dictionary within dictionary

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to display values from a dictionary within a dictionary in a template using django.
I have a dictionary like this in my views:

```
characters = {
        "char1": {'name': "David",
                   'stars': 4,
                   'series': "All star"},
        "char2": {'name': "Patrick",
                   'stars': 3,
                   'series': "Demi god"}
}
```

I can display the whole dictionary on the page, however I want to display only the 'name' and 'David' key:value pairs. I wrote the following in the template:

```
{% for char in characters  %}
    {% for key, value in char %}
      {{ key }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However this doesn't show me anything. What is wrong with this double loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kfarnell's help I finally managed to get this:

```
{% for character, params in characters.items %}
   {{ params.name }}: {{ params.stars }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [.items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.item) when you loop through key value pairs. 
See below (Python 3):

```
{% for char in characters.items %}
  {% for c in char %}
    name: {{ c.name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In Python 2 it would be .iteritems

```
{% for char in characters.iteritems %}
  {% for c in char %}
      name: {{ c.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm using python3 and I followed your suggestion but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: I fixed my answer

Comment: It's working, however 'name'(not the variable) is displayed twice for each character. I'm guessing this is because of the double for loop? How can this be prevented?

Comment: Yeah, it keeps showing double of whatever I insert there. For example if I enter name: {{ c.name }} I get name: name: David. Any idea how this could be resolved?

Comment: OK, I got this now! I'm going to post it now